# Will my singleton be killed?

Tags: java, android, service, singleton, foreground-service

I have an application where I create a foreground service to make sure a user initiated upload continues even if the user quits the app or app is killed by memory pressure.

Both the service and app use a singleton to pass data around. I know this is not the best solution, so kindly ask to refrain from comments about bad-bad singletons as the question is not in this but in the following:

When I close the app, my foreground service continues running and can access the singleton. Is there a risk of the singleton being garbage collected due to memory pressure or are there any other memory related risks of using a singleton in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static variables are only destroyed when the application is killed.  So they won't just randomly disappear while your service is running.  However if your entire service restarts you do have to account for the possibility of not having the singleton when it restarts.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is nothing bad about singletons. But as any other pattern or method it just could be used improperly.
2. Due to memory pressure or any other reason a system could kill your app. But your `Service` will be relaunched later.

Comment: My service is a **foreground** service, meaning the chances of it being killed due to memory pressure are negligent. Question is once activity is killed, is there a chance of singleton going with it?

Comment: @AlexandreG if your singleton is somehow connected with `gc root` then `gc` literally can't eliminate your singleton. It seems you mix gc and system notions.  System kills process, but gc just objects without references to the `gc root`.

Comment: Being a foreground service doesn't count for as much as you think-  they can get killed too, they just get killed later.  In fact I think most services lie and say they're foreground these days.

Comment: @GabeSechan According to android docs they have same priority as the active app open on your screen. Yeah they can get killed as well, but that's like saying - don't rely on your service - your phone might be stolen, is it not?

Comment: @AlexandreG I'm saying that pretty much all services lie and say they're foreground so they get killed less frequently.  So in low memory Android will have to still choose and kill one.  It makes it less frequent, but far from impossible-  it still happens relatively frequently.  You need to be prepared to handle that, especially if you try to restart.  So not a "don't use that" but more a "program defensively and assume the worst".

Comment: @GabeSechan It's somewhat hard to lie about it as Android forces you to have a non-dismissable notification for one.. I understand your point though, thanks for your answer

Comment: @AlexandreG That wasn't a requirement on older versions of Android.  The old function was setForeground and only took a boolean.  Its still accessible for compatibility and likely via reflection (haven't tried that).  I would also bet a notification with a custom view that's empty would probably work, but I haven't tried that either.

Answer (score 0):

1. Singleton pattern is a very useful pattern in the system due to that it is a static format. Exactly one object is needed to coordinate actions across the system. You dont need to worry about the duplication or you accidentally create multiple modules.
2. A foreground service is a service that's considered to be something the user is actively aware of(has focus) and thus not a candidate for the system to kill when low on memory. The skeleton object will not be killed.